# create Ajax.ActionLink Link text dynamic from model in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to create the ajax.actionlink dynamic from model. so that on base of that list i need to short the product. The code i tried so far is

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Color)
        {

         @Ajax.ActionLink("@item.Color", "All", new AjaxOptions
    {
    HttpMethod="GET",
    UpdateTargetId="",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

    })

        }
```

but the output from @item.Color is coming as string instead of list of color. Is it possible to generate Link text dynamic

and my Viewbag is 
 ViewBag.Color = me.tblColors.ToList();

Comment: Remove the quotes around `@item.Color`

Comment: You will need to cast it - `@Ajax.ActionLink((string)item.Color, ...` (But stop using `ViewBag` and use a model!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is using ViewBag is Bad ?

Comment: `ViewBag` is `dynamic`. Its always better to pass a model to the view (in the view it would be `@model IEnumerable<yourAssembly.Color>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `@item.Color` and since your using `ViewBag`, you need to cast the property value to `string`.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Color)
{
  @Ajax.ActionLink((string)@item.Color, "All", new AjaxOptions
  {
    HttpMethod="GET",
    UpdateTargetId="",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
  })
}
```